# How to take inputs from 2 different users? AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want 2 different users to pass these 2 values.
Thats means num1 will contain the value which is send by user1 and num2 containing user2's value.
In general, I just want 2 users interacting with each other.
How should I code it??

Comment: Haven't you tried anything?

Comment: How are you matching the two users? This is not a trivial problem, and will involve some planning server-side.

Comment: This isn't my code. I just placed an example.
And I haven't tried yet, cause I don't have any idea of it! I tried google but still I got more confused.

Comment: 2 different users means 2 different sessions where each user would use the same form element but be identified by some other criterium, e.g. a login ...

Comment: lol if it is not your code then please remove it. Its no use because it does not explain anything.Did you tried session ?

Comment: AJAX or "the server" do not have a concept of a "user". They only see a client, the browser and _maybe_ a session referred to by a client. So I do not see a way to differ between two users inside a single html page.

Comment: So I should use session! right? But how, can you tell me something more..?

Comment: @user3545779 is there any loging system in your application? if yes you have already set the session for logged in user, use that session

Comment: Yes I have!I can get session from there..!but how should I use it with ajax?

Comment: @user3545779 see my answer it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a page through ajax say getuser.php

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",   
    url: "getuser.php", 
    success: function(result)
    {
       console.log(result); // here you will get logged in user session id

    }
});
```

getuser.php

```
<?php

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['id']; // Assuming your session name is id

?>
```

**OR**

If you want user details of logged in user, then you can fetch from database against the session id.